# I cant read text file on click of ListView item in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to read a text file on click of ListView Item click in Android..
i want to make an Android application in which i created ListView in that some list of string..so if i click on ListView Item a text file will be open how to do this in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
```

You may need a class `Filechooser` where you can send an intent to

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, FileChooser.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
// Instanciating an array list
ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
//add file names    

// This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a 
// first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your 
// array as a third parameter.
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
         this, 
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
         your_array_list );

listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        String file_name = your_array_list.get(position);
        File file = new File(dirPath, file_name);
        //do stuff
    }           
});
```